# Understanding and Troubleshooting `cin.peek()` in C++ for XML-like Parsing

Tags: attributes

I'm working on a C++ program for parsing XML-like tags and attributes, and I have a specific question related to the use of `cin.peek()`. In my code, I'm using `if (cin.peek() == '/')` to check the next character, but it doesn't seem to behave as expected.

here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<map>
#include<algorithm>
#include<string>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std                                         ;

vector<string> tag_stack                                    ;
map<string,string> attr                                     ;
void insert(string & name ,string & val)                    {
    string full                                             ;
    for(string & str : tag_stack)                           {
        full += str + "."                                   ;}
    full.pop_back()                                         ;
    full += "~" + name                                      ;
    attr[full] = val                                        ;}
int main()                                                  {
    int n,q                                                 ;
    cin>>n>>q                                               ;

    for(int i =0;i<n;++i)                                   {
        char c                                              ;
        cin>>c                                              ;
        if(cin.peek() == '/')                               {
            string cn                                       ;
            cin>>cn                                         ;
            tag_stack.pop_back()                            ;}
        else                                                {
            string name                                     ;
            cin>>name                                       ;
            if(name.back()== '>')                           {
                name.pop_back()                             ;
                tag_stack.push_back(name)                   ;}
            else                                            {
                tag_stack.push_back(name)                   ;
                for(;;)                                     {
                    string attr_name,eq,attr_value          ;
                    cin >> attr_name >> eq >> attr_value    ;
                    if(attr_value.back() == '>')            {
                        attr_value.pop_back()               ;
                        attr_value.pop_back()               ;
                        attr_value = attr_value.substr(1)   ;
                        insert(attr_name,attr_value)        ;
                        break                               ;}
                
                    else                                    {
                        attr_value.pop_back()               ;
                        attr_value = attr_value.substr(1)   ;
                        insert(attr_name,attr_value)        ;
                                                            }}}}}
    for(int i=0;i<q;++i)                                    {
        string queue                                        ;
        cin>>queue                                          ;
        if(attr.find(queue) != attr.end())                  {
            
            cout<<attr[queue]<<endl                         ;}
        else                                                {
            cout<<"Not Found!"<<endl                        ;}
                                                            }

    return 0                                                ;}

 Your code segment with the if (cin.peek() == '/') condition
```

Your code segment with the if (cin.peek() == '/') condition i dont understand this condition can you explain how this works